# Getting Assertion Error in rest assured API

Tags: java, rest-assured, assertion

**I am trying to run this script to extract address information**.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;

import io.restassured.matcher.ResponseAwareMatcher;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import org.testng.Assert;

import Files.Payload;
public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://rahulshettyacademy.com";
        String response=given().log().all().queryParam("key", "qaclick123").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(Payload.AddPlace()).when().post("maps/api/place/add/json")
        .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).body("scope",equalTo("APP"))
        .header("Server", "Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)").extract().response().asString();
        
        System.out.println(response);
        JsonPath js=new JsonPath(response);//for parsing json
        String PlaceId = js.getString("place_id");
        System.out.println(PlaceId);
        
        //update place
        String newAddress = "Summerwalk, Africa";
        given().log().all().queryParam("key", "qaclik123").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body("{\r\n"
                + "\"place_id\":\""+PlaceId+"\",\r\n"
            + "\"address\":\""+newAddress+"\",\r\n"
                + "\"key\":\"qaclick123\"\r\n"
                + "}").
        when().put("maps/api/place/update/json").
        then().assertThat().log().all().statusCode(200).body("msg", equalTo("Address successfully updated"));
        
        //get place 
        String getPlaceResponse= given().log().all().queryParam("key", "qackick123")
                .queryParam("place_id", PlaceId)
                .when().get("maps/api/place/get/json")
                .then().assertThat().log().all().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();
                
                JsonPath js1= new JsonPath(getPlaceResponse);
                String actualAddress = js1.getString("address");
                System.out.println(actualAddress);
        
    }   
    
}
```

**Result:**

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://rahulshettyacademy.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=qaclick123
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   key=qaclick123
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "location": {
        "lat": -38.383494,
        "lng": 33.427362
    },
    "accuracy": 50,
    "name": "Frontline house",
    "phone_number": "(+91) 983 893 3937",
    "address": "29, side layout, cohen 09",
    "types": [
        "shoe park",
        "shop"
    ],
    "website": "http://google.com",
    "language": "French-IN"
}
{"status":"OK","place_id":"4a9c2d6cfdbe1736b0ea14ddf13a6c67","scope":"APP","reference":"5165d657949509007fa0e486a5d90f635165d657949509007fa0e486a5d90f63","id":"5165d657949509007fa0e486a5d90f63"}
4a9c2d6cfdbe1736b0ea14ddf13a6c67
Request method: PUT
Request URI:    https://rahulshettyacademy.com/maps/api/place/update/json?key=qaclik123
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   key=qaclik123
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "place_id": "4a9c2d6cfdbe1736b0ea14ddf13a6c67",
    "address": "Summerwalk, Africa",
    "key": "qaclick123"
}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2023 21:26:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Content-Length: 38
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "msg": "Address successfully updated"
}
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://rahulshettyacademy.com/maps/api/place/get/json?key=qackick123&place_id=4a9c2d6cfdbe1736b0ea14ddf13a6c67
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   key=qackick123
                place_id=4a9c2d6cfdbe1736b0ea14ddf13a6c67
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2023 21:26:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Content-Length: 67
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "msg": "Get operation failed, looks like place_id  doesn't exists"
}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:512)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:696)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.this$2$validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:135)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:143)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
    at Basics.main(Basics.java:44)
```

This code runs as expected till PUT method. But it shows error for GET method as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. Expected status code <200> but was <404>.

When I remove the code for "Get place", the code works fine.
**Please help me to fix this error.**

Comment: It seems API is working incorrectly, pls ask rahulshettyacademy.

Comment: Okay, so problem is with the API. Thanks for clarifying it.